# Let R clock its operations

Tags: r

I want to observe how performant R is with really big data sets and make some comparisons to other statistical software. Is it possible to let R clock its calculations and operations? I need something telling me like "Last task took 43ms", or something like that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See `Sys.time` or `microbenchmark` package.

Comment: @agstudy I think you mean `system.time()`

Comment: @hadley of course `system.time()`!

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want, `Rprof` profiler can help too.

Comment: Thanks, gonna try this.